# Where can I find the IComparable's CompareTo method definition?

Tags: c#, oop

Where can I find the CompareTo method definition?

As the Below code, I can get the use of CompareTo method by implementing IComparable interface. But I haven't given any definition for the CompareTo method in my Utilities class. I know this is a very trivial question to ask. But I don't understand how a Class implements an interface without giving its method implementation.

```
public class Utilities<T> where T : IComparable
    {
        public T Max(T a, T b)  
        {
            return a.CompareTo(b) > 0 ? a : b;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `Utilities` class is not implementing `IComparable`. You are saying that `T` must implement `IComparable`. If `Utilities` were to implement `IComparable`, it would look like this:

```
public class Utilities<T> : IComparable
```

You don't need to define a `CompareTo` method in `Utilities` because that should be defined in `T`, whatever `T` is.

For example, you can't use `Foo` for `T` because `Foo` does not implement `IComparable`:

```
class Foo { 
   // you must add a CompareTo method here in order to use Foo as T
   // you must also add ": IComparable"
}
```

But you *can* use `string` or `int` or `float` because they do implement `IComparable`.

Answer (score 2):

You are using [generic type constraint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters) rather than implement `IComparable` interface, Which means `T` must implement from `IComparable`.

If you want to implement `IComparable` interface you need to use `:` after class name and before `where`constraint keyword.

```
public class Utilities<T> : IComparable 
    where T : IComparable

{
    public int CompareTo(object obj)
    {

    }

    public T Max(T a, T b)
    {
        return a.CompareTo(b) > 0 ? a : b;
    }
}
```